# How to use react hooks inside of HOC component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem making a HOC component with hooks inside.

I am trying to find a correct solution to not break `rules-of-hooks`.

If I change the name of this component to start with lowercase: `withNetworkDetector`
instead of uppercase, I will not get errors, but did I break the rule then?

Is this code will be secure then?

```
export const WithNetworkDetector = (Component: FC<{}>) => (props: any) => {
  const [isDisconnected, setIsDisconnected] = useState(false);

  const handleConnectionChange = useCallback(() => {
   ...
    setIsDisconnected(true);
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <div>
      {isDisconnected && (
          <Toast type="warning" text={TOAST_ERRORS.LOST_INTERNET_CONNECTION} />
      )}
      <Component />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can be used inside the React functional component. One of the criterias that classify a function as a react function is the name starting in uppercase, then only we can use that as a React component. So, it will break the rule.